# SOQL on Rich text fields long text

Tags: soql, sosl, richtextarea, long-text-area

I'm working on a custom search page, which will search through the fields of the Project object. I use dynamic SOQL query similar to that:

```
SELECT Id, 
            Name, 
            Link_Test__c, 
            Technology_Sinonym__c, 
            Internal_Synonym__c, 
            Innovators__c 
    FROM Technology__c 
    WHERE(Technology_Limitations__c != 'ddd' AND Name != 'www') 
    ORDER BY Name DESC LIMIT 50
```

but the error that display :

> Error: field 'Technology_Limitations__c' can not be filtered in query
>   call

this filed id Rich Text so I know I cant use where operator in SOQL 
so I am wonder if I can use in SOSL or Do you have author solution

Comment: Welcome to SF Stack Exchange.  Your question seems to be asking the same as this recent question: [Filtering by Long Text Area field in SOQL](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21298/filtering-by-long-text-area-field-in-soql)  You should be able to find your answer in here. (Unfortunately, it might not make you happy.)

Comment: but I am asking if i can use in SOSL to do that casue i didnt use in sosl at all and i wonder if to do this way or to try to learn this

Comment: I suppose that does make it a slightly different question.  Unfortunately the answer is still the same.  I think I just came up with a workaround though and will soon post it.

Comment: Currently this question is very SOQL oriented and it's not entirely clear what type of response you're receiving regarding SOSL. Would you consider editing/updating your question and title to highlight the specific question around SOSL and what you've tried in SOSL ?

Comment: i didnt know SOSL but i am asking if it possible in SOSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discovered a work around for this here.  Create a Formula field that uses the LEFT formula and filter on that.  You cannot filter on the ENTIRE long text but you can filter on part of it:

Legal_Street__c is a long text area.  I created a formula field call StreetConc__c:

```
LEFT(Legal_Street__c, 40)
```

I then created a dummy record and put the text 'testingthis' in the Legal_Street__c field.  From here I filtered on this formula field.

```
System.debug('answer = ' + [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE StreetConc__c LIKE 'testing%']);
```

You should be able to apply this to both SOQL and SQL.

NOTE: You don't need to use 40 for the LEFT in the formula field.  It was just an example.

Comment: but i dont understand  how can its help string text not equal to rich text

Comment: @Racheli Rich text **IS** string text.  When it is displayed to the User, it just applies the html to what the User sees.  It might instead make sense to use '%testing%' so that you can find specific words inside of tags as well.  It is definitely more complex to search on but this is the closest you will get.